# Redirecionar usuário de acordo com o nome do login

Tags: php, redirecionamento

Estou tentando colocar um sistema de login, onde quem acessar seu login vai ter acesso a uma pagina diferente. Estou usando php e mysql, mas sou muito iniciante no assunto. Queria que o sistema funcionasse assim:

login:lucas
senha:lucas

A pessoa seria encaminhada para uma página específica

login:daniel
senha:daniel

A pessoa seria encaminhada para outra página

---

Bom, devo ter deixado a pergunta um pouco incopleta e or isso vim aqui completa-la:

tentei criar um sistema de cadastro e um de login, onde o de login ele vai te encaminhar para uma pagina que no caso vai ser "www.site.com.br/usuario"

os codigos etao na pasta baixo:

http://pastebin.com/VtgMfFhQ

Comment: O que você já tentou? Adicione o código na pergunta clicando em [edit]

Comment: voce pode adicionar mais uma coluna no seu banco contendo a pagina para qual o usuario irá ser direcionado. Assim, depois que validar o usuario voce usuaria a função header("location: xxxxx") para direcionar o usuario para a pagina correspondente

Answer (score 1):

Não há nenhum código publicado irei dizer um genérico:

```
<?

if($lucas){
header('location: https://example.com/lucas');
}

if($daniel){
header('location: https://example.com/daniel');
}

?>
```

**Observações:**

Também pode fazer o seguinte, para todos os usuários:

```
header('location: https://example.com/'.$nome); 
//terá o mesmo resultado neste caso
```

**Nota:**

Se utiliza editores como Dreamweaver é preciso desligar o BOM ao salvar o arquivo, isso pode ser feito em Opções Unicode e desmarcar, quando for salvar, caso contrario será enviado um resultado antes de redirecionar o que pode causar erro. Além, obviamente não ter espaços antes de `<?php` ou qualquer outro `echo` antes do header.

Comment: A pergunta não está clara, não tem nem como exemplificar, senão gera uma resposta ruim ou ampla demais(e vira tutorial).

Comment: Sim. Respondi apenas para dar  uma ideia do que poderia ser feito, do como poderia redirecionar, talvez essa seja a questão. Não há como saber nem como está estruturado, nem como quer redirecionar. Enfim, tentei ajudar, somente.

Comment: Então, não me leve a mal, mas uma pergunta ruim gerou uma resposta não tão boa. Seu exemplo não faz muito sentido.

Comment: Não sei qual o projeto. Geralmente quando querem redirecionar para página diferente é baseado pelo nome ou id. Por exemplo, entra na sua conta e aparece seu perfil, por isso dei o segundo exemplo, que acredito ser o mais  útil. Se ele der mais detalhes eu edito a resposta (se a pergunta não for removida). "Sou novo" - sempre visito mas pouco respondo - no Stackoverflow, mas irei evitar responder perguntas muito abrangentes em futuras visitas.

Comment: Sua boa vontade é louvável, mas é bom as vezes o OP não obter resposta com uma pergunta fraca, para que no futuro, elabore melhor a pergunta não acha? Enfim, talvez o que parece não ser bom pra mim, seja util pro OP, vamos esperar que ele analise sua resposta. :)

Answer (score 1):

No `.htaccess` insira esses dados:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dados"
AuthUserFile /home/host/public_html/<DIRETORIO>/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Já no `.htpasswd` basta acessar o site http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ para gerar um login e senha, que como exemplo, usaremos este:

```
administrador:$apr1$5tnojPc/$QVe0Hkbg4ymK8NJHdkCDk0
```

Login: administrador
Senha: senhateste

:)

Answer (score 0):

Se quer uma forma de acessar diretórios ao inserir um login e senha sem que seja necessário o uso de um banco de dados e uma página de login/registro, acredito que com o [`.htpasswd`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) funcione.

Comment: O ideal seria mostrar um exemplo de htpasswd que redirecionasse conforme o login

Comment: agora como faria pra cria a pagina do cliente:
no caso criei o usuario: teste, entao ele vai ser encaminhado para o site www.site.com.br/teste, mas a pagina que eu vou criar o html, vai ser teste.html? e ela tem que ficar na mesma pasta que o index do site? se assim estiver funcionaria com as correçoes de codigo?

Comment: Cada pasta que você criar será referente a um cliente, logo, você pode criar uma pasta chamada Clientes e cada subpasta referente a cada cliente de fato. Dentro de cada pasta de cliente conteria os arquivos .htaccess e .htpasswd junto com um index.html onde podem ser modificado os dados de cada cliente